# Python xml.etree issue

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to build a script in python 3 using xml.etree which accepts version as a parameter ,  parses xml and replace the version in the xml tags + values from the tree to the root and his children.

I am at the point where i can change the  default value in the root but i am struggling with  changing the version to childs and grandchilds - CurrentVersion, Template and Base.

Here is my code and XML:

**code-**

```
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
version = sys.argv[1]
parse = et.parse("WebApp2.config")
root = parse.getroot()

def changeVersion(version):
    ourVersion = root.find('OurVersion')
    root.set("default", version)
    print(et.tostring(root))
    parse.write("WebApp2.config", xml_declaration=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    changeVersion(version)
```

**XML-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OurVersion default="1.0.0.3">
  <CurrentVersion bitSupport="true" deviceDetectionSupport="true" 
  version="1.0.0.3">
    <Template>D:\Some\Path\Software\1.0.0.3\webApp\index.webapp</Template>
    <BasePath>resources/1.0.0.3/webApp/</BasePath>
  </CurrentVersion>
 </OurVersion>
```

I've tried to add something like the below, but im getting issue that "no set attribue to currentVersion" -

```
ourVersion = root.find('OurVersion')
ourVersion.set('default`, version)
currentVersion = ourVersion.find('CurrentVersion')
currentVersion.set('version', version)
```

Appreciate your help on this matter ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first script works because with `root.set("default", version)` you are using `root` to refer to the attribute `default` that you want to modify.

In fact `ourVersion = root.find('OurVersion')` returns nothing (`None`) because 
`OurVersion` **is** your root and then `ourVersion.find('CurrentVersion')` cannot return what you expect.

Try this instead :

```
currentVersion = root.find('CurrentVersion')
currentVersion.set('version', version)
```

Comment: Thanks alot !!   how can i also refer to the text inside the tags and find a specific string there ?  i mean changing Template and BasePath?

Comment: you can just use `currentVersion.find('Template').text`